# iptable v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to making a simple firewall using this article  https://raspberrytips.com/raspberry-pi-firewall/ . I try many ways but i get same error for this code
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.42.1:3128` and `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128`
ERROR is `iptable v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"` Please Help me :(.

Comment: If the kernel isn't compiled with support for iptables over nftables or similar things, some features won't work. So Is that a custom kernel (not provided by RaspberryPi OS)? What kernel is it from which RaspberryPi OS version and what compile options? Also does it change behavior if `-p tcp` is replaced with `-p tcp -m tcp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just registered to answer this question because I had a similar problem: I tried to let a docker container run on my Raspberry Pi (Zero 2 W) with Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) installed. I used the command `docker run -p [port mapping] [container name]` which resulted in the same error message because it apparently uses iptables internally.

From [this](https://serverfault.com/a/249726) answer from Sacx I learned that Debian systems (which Raspbian belongs to) do not come with an init script for iptables. To fix that all that has to be done is initializing it via

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

This has the nice side effect that it loads the iptables on every boot too. ([see](https://blog.mxard.com/persistent-iptables-on-raspberry-pi-raspbian))